# PostgreSQL FOREIGN KEY with second database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running the following queries on PostgreSQL 9.3:

```
CREATE TABLE "app_item" 
  ( 
     "id"          SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     "location_id" UUID NOT NULL 
  ); 

CREATE INDEX app_item_e274a5da 
  ON "app_item" ("location_id"); 

ALTER TABLE "app_item" 
  ADD CONSTRAINT app_item_location_id_5cecc1c0b46e12e2_fk_fias_addrobj_aoguid 
  FOREIGN KEY ("location_id") REFERENCES "fias_addrobj" ("aoguid") deferrable 
  initially deferred;
```

Third query returns:

> ERROR: relation "fias_addrobj" does not exist

- `app_item` - table in first database
- `fias_addrobj` - table in second database

How to do correct query with this databases?

Comment: There is no way to create a FK to a table in other database.

Comment: If need to do something like this, you'll have to use different *schemas*. It's definitely not possible across databases.

Comment: You could use triggers to enforce FK constraints and in turn maintain referential integrity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not had occasion to use this myself, but you might want to look into *Foreign Data Wrappers*, which are essentially the successor to `dblink`. In particular, [postgres-fdw](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html).

Once the general setup of the *fdw* is in place (steps 1-3 in the link above), you could create a *foreign table* via `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE`, defined like the table in your remote DB, and then use that table as part of the *foreign key* `CONSTRAINT`, and see if it works.

If that doesn't work, another option would be to have a process which ETL's the data (say, via a *Python* script) from the remote server over to the local server (say, on an hourly or daily basis, depending on the size), and then you would have a true local table to use in the *foreign key* `CONSTRAINT`. It wouldn't be real-time, but depending on your needs, may suffice.

Comment: Foreign keys are not supported for foreign tables: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37380738/2199492

Answer (score 5):

A local table must be referenced

However, as stated within the below link, you could maybe use a trigger which uses a cross server join (facilitated by [`dblink`](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html)) to simulate the built-in methods for constraining?

For instance, you could have a trigger set up that on `INSERT`, checks to see if a given FK exists to aid with enforcing referential integrity, or on `DELETE` to cascade

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=101322

P.S. Would avoid this at all costs.

Comment: Even with dblink I don't think you can create a FK to a different database.

Comment: > P.S. Would avoid this at all costs.
 So true...